# Why do I have such inconsistent results when training my model?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I am using Keras to train my model.

I have initialised `numpy` and `tensorflow` seeds. I have made a 50-iterations loop where I train and test my Keras deep learning architecture (always the same) on the same training, validation and test sets. I get those results :

```
print (np.mean(train_accuracy_vec))
print (np.std(train_accuracy_vec))
print ()
print (np.mean(valid_accuracy_vec))
print (np.std(valid_accuracy_vec))
print ()
print (np.mean(test_accuracy_vec))
print (np.std(test_accuracy_vec))
print ()
```

I get this :

[image]

Sometimes it gives an unacceptable false positive rates while sometimes, it works quite well. I used `EarlyStopping` based on `val_acc` behaviour.

So, what could cause a so great instability ?

Also isn't it a bit odd to have validation score far under test score ?

Thanks

EDIT: Despite @Thomas Pinetz kind answer, I don't get better results at the second time : still high std...

To be more precise, here is how my loop is made :

```
# tf, random and numpy seeds...
# lots of data reading, preprocessing,...(including split between train, valid and test sets) 
for k in range (0,50) :
    print (k)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(200, activation='elu', input_dim=trainX.shape[1], init=keras.initializers.glorot_uniform(1)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    # some additional layers...
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(validX, validY), epochs=100, verbose=0 , callbacks=callbacks_list)  

    train_score = model.evaluate(trainX, trainY)
    train_accuracy_vec.append (train_score[1])
    print(train_score)
    trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
    print(confusion_matrix(trainY, trainPredict.round()))

    # and the same for valid and test...
```

[image]

Comment: Are your test, validation, and train sets all from the same distribution?

Comment: @marco_gorelli they should, as they come from the same dataset and are randomly chosen... But anyway, I don't see why different distributions between sets could lead to unconsistent results, as my sets remain exactly the same from one iteration to another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain reproducable results in keras follow the following instructions: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development.

It might be that multi-threading is causing problems.

Edit:

Every time you run a method, that returns a random number, this number depends on your initial seed. So while your script always returns the same values, e.g. same mean and std for your training/val/test set evaluation it will not use the same random number in each iteration of the for loop.

What you can try is to loop around the entire script and set the random set at the beginning of the for loop. Maybe then you will get the same results.

There is all kind of randomness in generating and training a DL model. From the initialization of the weights to the order of your training set, which by default is random. This initialization will not be the same if you do not reset the random seed. Same for the order of the dataset. In each epoch your training data is shuffled and this will be different in every for loop run. There are also layers which use stochastic elements like dropout, which need the same seed to guarantee the same performance.

Comment: Yes it is taken into account.

Comment: Do you run the script multiple times or do you have a loop around your code? If you have a loop around your code you will naturally not get the same initial seed.

Comment: Let me just ask you if what is described in "Randomness from Using the GPU" paragraph of https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/ is taken into account in your link ?

Comment: So the initial seeds are obviously the same each time I run the model

Comment: Thanks now I see... I haven't tested yet your proposal but I am a bit surprised anyway that I have a so great variability in the results at each time... Nothing to advise on the architecture itself to stabilize ?

Comment: You do not actually have great variability in your model. I mean your std is 0.0x. That is quite small. In non-convex optimization it does matter where you start to optimize and that is why good papers often report a box plot on the final accuracy to show the variability of the model with different random seed. Exactly like you just did. I would guess that smaller models are less prone to overfit and therefore be variable than larger models, but I have no theoretical justification for that.

Comment: My std deviation is linked with accuracy, so a standard deviation of 0.03 actually means a std deviation of 3% on the accuracy (measured between 0 and 100%)...

Comment: I know that is not much for NNs.

Answer (score 2):

What causes differences between runs is the random initialization of weights. Gradient-descent based methods get stuck in local minima, so, the best solution that will be found on each run depends on the initial weights. There's not much you can do about that. It's inherent problem of neural networks. It might help to take a look at Xavier/He initialization though.

As to why your validation error is quite worse than the test error, it's indeed weird. However, if your dataset is relatively small, and you are using the same splitting at all runs, it might have just happened that the test set has similar patterns to the training set, while the validation has different. You'd better split at each run.

Comment: Dataset is not quite small :). But thank you for Xavier/He. Your answer seems complementary to @Thomas Pinetz 'one

Comment: Which one should I take in Keras ? I saw this paper : https://keras.io/initializers/ but it seems like I have the "choice"...

Comment: @MysteryGuy: in your link, the `glorot_normal` seems to be xavier initialization. On the other hand, if you use `Zeros()` or `Ones()` your results should be reproducible (I haven't used keras, but it makes sense)

Comment: I tested both (complementary) ans still get bad results for sure (std dev of around 0.03 which is quite high...)